# Not running with FAB

Tags: android, android-layout

I had used fab in a layout, but when running give the following errors

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.ahr.a1000funnysms, PID: 26295
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
> at com.example.ahr.a1000funnysms.SmsPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(SmsPagerAdapter.java:34)
> at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
> at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1182)
> at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
> at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
> at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
> at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
> at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
> at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
> at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16552)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1923)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1302)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1007)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5677)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.jav

without using FAB, there is no such error

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your whole xml.

Comment: have you added dependencies of design `compile 'com.android.support:design:x.x.x'` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'`  for floating button like below code

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

FAB button is Design Library Cpmponent. Your Activity must extend **AppCompatActivity** instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change following line:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/pay"
```

with this one:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/pay"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in style.xml => Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar